# Cscope insensitive search

Tags: regex, vim, grep, cscope

I am trying to do a case insentive search in vim with cscope. For example:

```
:cs find e regexp
```

Should find regexp, REGEXP, Regexp and so on... How can I do this? I've been trying the (?i) in front of the expression, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:cs find e` expects an `egrep` pattern. Since `egrep` is not case-insensitive by default there's no reason to expect the pattern `regexp` to match `regexp`, `REGEXP`, etc.

Also, `egrep` doesn't honor `(?i)`.

To make cscope's search (all search methods, not only `egrep`) case-insensitive by default, you must add the `-C` flag to your initialization command:

```
:cscope add cscope.out -C
```

Comment: Yes, but this sucks on the longer run, as I only needed the case insensitive for some searches and case sensitive for other.

Anyway, thanks for clearing this up.

Comment: For me when I try to add the `-C` switch while adding the database I get a stat error, which reads `E563: stat(/dbc/blr-dbc202/AJ/CSCOPE_DB/CSCOPE_KERNEL_MAIN/cscope.out) error: 2` however when I add it without the `-C` option, it gets added.

Secondly, it gets autoloaded when I invoke it from within the same directory like these:
`/usr/bin/cscope -dl -f cscope.out`. So if I try to add it with the `-C` switch again (from within VIM) it doesn't allow me. Could you help?

Comment: `:cscope add cscope.out -C` simply does NOT work for me . (`VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4`)

Answer (score 1):

For me, [romainl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26904530/9593596) didn't work. Instead,

```
set csprg=cscope\ -C
```

did the job.